# Android Flush UI

Tags: android, ui-thread

Sometimes I've got situations that I want to make "light" operation like showing UI view and after that I want to show large set of UI views. I make it this way:

```
smallView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
largeSetOfViews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

the result is that smallView and largeSetOfViews become visible at the same moment.

I want to make:

```
smallView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
FLUSH_UI
largeSetOfViews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to have smallView visible before largeSetOfViews will be visible.

To make flush I do:

```
smallView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        largeSetOfViews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Is there any better solution for making Flush UI?

Comment: have you tried Thread.sleep(long) before setvisibility of largesetofviews?

Comment: Yes, it also works, the same as Handler.postDelayed, but it's not pure flush. We have no guarantee that argument for sleep function will be enough to show view.